# jQuery var undefined after 1 loop(variable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, for-loop

I am running a loop, that checks div's for it's content(its a small 4 pieced puzzle, data taken from XML files. Now i have a variable that makes it run trough div #1A to #4A. now i use the same variable to go into the div, and see if there is an image with the same class as parent id has. this is my jquery:

```
        //Run this when they want to check the answer
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var correctPositions = 0;

            function handleForm(count) {
                //Build div var
                console.log("clickDetected");
                var div = "#"+ count +"A";
                console.log("This is the counter "+count);
                console.log("This is the div im looking into: "+div);

                //Check if div actually has children
                if ($(div).children().length > 0){
                    var childId = $(div + ":first-child").attr("id");
                    //Got HTML to test if there really wasn't anything, returns: undefined
                    var childHTML = $(div + ":first-child").html();
                    console.log(childHTML);
                    if(childId != null){
                        console.log("Child id "+ childId);
                        if(count = childId){
                            correctPositions++;
                            console.log("Correct answers:"+correctPositions);
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log("child is undefined");
                    }
                }
                console.log("end of IF");
            }

            //Bind click to function
            $("#goed").click(function() {
                //Loops 4 times
                for(count = 1; count < 5; count++) {
                    handleForm(count);
                }                   
            }); 
        });
```

This is the HTML when all puzzle pieces are on the right place.

```
                <div id="pieceHolder">
                    <div class="position one ui-droppable" id="1A"><span style="display:none;" id="1">1</span></div>
                    <div class="position two ui-droppable" id="2A"><span style="display:none;" id="2">2</span></div>
                    <div class="position three ui-droppable" id="3A"><span style="display:none;" id="3">3</span></div>
                    <div class="position four ui-droppable" id="4A"><span style="display:none;" id="4">4</span></div>
                </div>
```

First div is fine, it finds the child span and it's ID. Only, when i get to the second div, it still finds the parent div, but says there is no child, and thus, no puzzle piece to be found.
What am i missing?

Comment: it's not efficient way to do in for loop on click.

Comment: Also it's not valid code of `id` attribute to start with a digit.

Comment: Just trying to learn stuff here, so improvements are welcome. Your comment is not really usefull..

Comment: Can u check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It has already been mentioned that you ought not to start an id with a digit.** But let say that that number is `4` for example. Then the following line:

```
var childId = $(div + ":first-child").attr("id");
```

Would be:

```
var childId = $("#4A:first-child").attr("id");
```

This does not refer to the first child of `#4A` if that is your intention. Already, `#4A` returns one element; so when you append `:first-child` the collection returned would be empty because `#4A` is not it's parent's `first-child`.

May be you meant to write:

```
var childId = $(div).children("span:first-child").attr("id");
```

Comment: I fixed the digit thing now. And thanks for this clear explanation, makes sense now!

Comment: Great! Glad I could be of help.